# Event handling MVVM WinRT

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

How do you handle events in MVVM in metro applications? I have used interaction class and EventToCommand from MVVM light in WPF but it seems there is no interaction in WinRT. There is also no triggers so do I have to "use ugly way"? (code behind and

`(this.DataContext as ViewModel).Command.Execute()`

for example?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best alternative to EventToCommand I have found so far is the attached command solution which has beem demonstrated in this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319855/Attached-Command-for-Windows-8-Metro-Style-in-C).

And that is how it is used.

```
<Button Content="Test Button"
 local:AttachedCommand.RoutedEvent="PointerEntered"
 local:AttachedCommand.Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
```

Another alternative is the [mimic of the EventToCommand](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.ch/2012/07/a-winrt-behavior-to-mimic-eventtocommand.html) behavior by Joost van Schaik but it was too heavy for me given the required dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately first solution doesn't work for me - InvalidOperationException is thrown (Adding or removing event handlers dynamically is not supported on WinRT events.). Could you give me some advices?

Comment: well I've found a solution here: http://www.guruumeditation.net/blog/events-and-mvvm-commands-in-metro. Would be great if someone could explain a bit how this OnEventToCommandEventChanged works (i mean what does and what is this WindowRuntimeMarshal code line in link).

Answer (score 0):

Attach commands using same method what we do in Silverlight except binding to the viewmodel will be using an interface and a class which implements it. This class should be used as a locator in the datacontext and declare it in the app.xaml.cs file as well. Please let me know if you need more details.